# Is Java8 code compiled by D8 only can run on some special Android OS version?

Tags: android, java-8

I saw Android studio 3.0 is rc1, what means D8 is coming soon with Java8 support. So If I use Java8 with D8 compiler, is this code can run on the low version of Android OS? Is there any special required for our application user?